# HTTP Request GET JSON and read data

Tags: json, swift

i have a problem by a code of me in swift. I do a request to webserver by httpMethod POST. This request is ok. I get a response and data inside the data value. The data looks like JSON

```
{"pushValues": {"devicePushGlobal":"1","devicePushNewProducts":"1","devicePushNewOffer":"1"}}
```

Then I will load this response data to set buttons based on the response data. But i fail to write this code. Can someone help me please? :)

Error Code
`Cannot invoke      'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with: NSString)'`
// i tested with other options but i always fail :-(

I comment the error in the code ....

```
let url = "https://URL.php"
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
let bodyData = "token=" + (dts)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) {
    (response, data, error) in

    // here i get the result of
    // {"pushValues": {"devicePushGlobal":"1","devicePushNewProducts":"1","devicePushNewOffer":"1"}}
    var str = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    var names = [String]()
    // here i will get each value of pushValues to add to the array names
    do {
        if let data = str,
        // ... and here is the error code by xcode ::: ==> Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with: NSString)'
        // i tested with other options but i always fail :-(
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any],
        let blogs = json["pushValues"] as? [[String: Any]] {
            for blog in blogs {
                if let name = blog["devicePushGlobal"] as? String {
                    print(name)
                    names.append(name)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
    }
    // names array is empty
    print(names)
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: remove `if let data = str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't decode the JSON response into an `NSString` using `var str = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)`. `JSONSerialization.jsonObject()` expects a `Data` object as an input argument, so just safely unwrap the optional `data` variable and use that as the input argument:

`if let responesData = data, let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData) as? [String: Any], let blogs = json["pushValues"] as? [String: Any]`

The full code using native Swift types:

```
...
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
...
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
    (response, data, error) in
    var names = [String]()
    do {
        if let responseData = data, let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData) as? [String: Any], let blogs = json["pushValues"] as? [String: Any]{
            if let name = blog["devicePushGlobal"] as? Int {
                print(name)
                names.append(name)
            }
            if let newProducts = blog["devicePushNewProducts"] as? Int{}
            if let newOffers = blog["devicePushNewOffers"] as? Int{}
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
    }
    // names array is empty
    print(names)
}).resume()
```

Comment: I got no output in console, see the print in the code .....`NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) {
(response, data, error) in
var names = [String]()
do {
                
**print(data) // CONSOLE ===>  Optional(93 bytes)**
                
if let responseData = data, let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData) as? [String: Any], let blogs = json["pushValues"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                    
**print("+++") // CONSOLE ===> no output, maybe json format wrong?**
                    
for blog in blogs {`

Comment: Please include the JSON response you (expect to) receive in your question, maybe its format is wrong.

Comment: {"pushValues": {"devicePushGlobal":"0","devicePushNewProducts":"0","devicePushNewOffer":"0"}}

Comment: Your values inside "pushValues" are Ints, change your parsing accordingly. `if let name = blog["devicePushGlobal"] as? Int`

Comment: Ok thank you, but i do a print after this following line and i don't see this print("+++") in the Console. So maybe the problem is in the following line because my json is wrong? `if let responseData = data, let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData) as? [String: Any], let blogs = json["pushValues"] as? [[String: Any]] { print("+++)"`

Comment: You can move the `let blogs = ...` part into another if statement and to see the json response.

Comment: Ok i do let blogs = ... into another if and print(json) the output in the console is `["pushValues": {
    devicePushGlobal = 1;
    devicePushNewOffer = 1;
    devicePushNewProducts = 1;
}]` so it looks ok, but the next if `if let blogs = json["pushValues"] as? [[String: Any]]  {
                    
                    print("+++")` will not be positive, so no +++ is in the console ... :-/

Comment: That's just a simple dictionary, not an array of dictionaries, so it should be `if let blogs = json["pushValues"] as? [String: Any]`

Comment: Thats good :) now after this i do `print(blogs)` the result is `["devicePushGlobal": 1, "devicePushNewProducts": 1, "devicePushNewOffer": 1]` but now on the last line `for blog in blogs {
                        if let name = blog["devicePushGlobal"] as? Int {` i got an error code by starting the app error code: `Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no member 'subscript'` sorry and thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Since blogs is now a `Dictionary`, you can't loop through it by indexes. You need to access its values using the known keys. See my updated answer.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please accept and upvote it.

Comment: To the left of the answer you can see a number (1 currently) with an up and down arrow above and below it. The upper arrow is the up vote icon and you can use the tick under the down arrow to accept the answer.